# Running migrations for a new added field which overrides save

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-migrations

I have been running a clinic management software where till now, I was having a patient registered by entering his details including age in years and months. This was stored in two IntegerFields. However I realized that next year if the same patient visits, his age would still be shown as the same. Hence I needed to create an approximate date of birth (I dont insist on patients giving their date of birth while registering.)

So I implemented a function which would calculate approximate date of birth from current age. I overrode the save method so that if a patient didnt enter date of birth, a caculated date would be inserted in the database.

My problem is creating this for existing customers. Once I updated my model with the new DateField, and the save method, on attempting to run makemigrations, I'm prompted to enter a default value, and I don't know how to make makemigrations use my function to update the records of existing patients. Do I just set the field to blank and null true, and then run a custom method to check if the field is blank, and update the field's data? Or can I make the makemigrations itself run the function I implemented? What's the proper way to do this?

My model and method:

```
class customer(models.Model):
    # Need autoincrement, unique and primary
    cstid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=35)
    ageyrs=models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    agemnths=models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    dob = models.DateField()
    gender_choices = (
        ('male', 'Male'),
        ('female', 'Female'),
        ('other', 'Something else'),
        ('decline', 'Decline to answer')
        )
    gender = models.CharField(
        choices=gender_choices, max_length=10, default='male')
    maritalstatus_choices = (
        ('unmarried', 'Unmarried'),
        ('married', 'Married')
                            )
    maritalstatus = models.CharField(
        choices=maritalstatus_choices, max_length=10, default='Unmarried')
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=15, default='')
    alternate = models.CharField(max_length=15, default='', blank=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='', blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=80, default='', blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=25, default='', blank=True)
    occupation = models.CharField(max_length=25, default='', blank=True)
    bloodgroup_choices = (('apos', 'A+'),
        ('aneg', 'A-'),
        ('bpos', 'B+'),
        ('bneg', 'B-'),
        ('opos', 'O+'),
        ('oneg', 'O-'),
        ('abpos', 'AB+'),
        ('abneg', 'AB-')
        )
    bloodgroup = models.CharField(choices=bloodgroup_choices, max_length=5, default='-', blank=True)
    linkedclinic = models.ForeignKey(Clinic, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ["name", "mobile", "linkedclinic"]


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.dob:
            current = datetime.datetime.now()
            newdate = current - relativedelta(years=self.ageyrs, months=self.agemnths)
            if not self.ageyrs == 0:
    #           datetime(year, month, day[, hour[, minute[, second[, microsecond[,tzinfo]]]]])
                dob = datetime.datetime(newdate.year, 1, 1)
            else:
                print("Age is less than 1 year")
                dob = newdate
            self.dob = dob
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)  # Call the "real" save() method.

    def age(self):
        if self.ageyrs == 0 and self.agemnths == 0:
            return "0yr"
        if self.ageyrs == 0:
            return str(self.agemnths) + "m"
        if self.agemnths == 0:
            return str(self.ageyrs) +"yr"
        return str(self.ageyrs) +"yr " +  str(self.agemnths) + "m"
```

On running makemigrations:

```
joel@hp:~/myappointments$ ./manage.py makemigrations
You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'dob' to customer without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
Select an option:
```

Answer (score 2):

Usually, I deal with such model changes using three migrations:

1. Add new field with `null=True`
2. Populate empty fields
3. Alter newly added field to `null=False`

The second migration could use `RunSQL` or `RunPython` and e.g. look like this:

```
def forward(apps, schema_editor):
    customer = apps.get_model("<app_name>", "customer")
    db_alias = schema_editor.connection.alias
    current = datetime.datetime.now()
    for c in customer.objects.using(db_alias).all():
        newdate = current - relativedelta(years=c.ageyrs, months=c.agemnths)
        if not self.ageyrs == 0:
            dob = datetime.datetime(newdate.year, 1, 1)
        else:
            print("Age is less than 1 year")
        dob = newdate
        c.dob = dob.date()
        c.save()


def rollback(apps, schema_editor):
    pass


...
    operations = [migrations.RunPython(forward, rollback)]
```

You can generate it using `python manage.py makemigrations <app_name> --empty`, and then modify it with proper data. When you will be creating a third migration, in the prompt you posted there will be a third option like "I dealt with this manually using in previous migration".